Problem with DependencyService in .NET MAUI for iOS: Cannot get an instance of IFileHelper, always return null
I'm working on a .NET MAUI application that uses DependencyService to get the local path to a file on iOS. Although I have followed the instructions to correctly register my IFileHelper implementation, I always get an exception stating that an IFileHelper instance cannot be obtained.
Code in the Shared Project
IFileHelper.cs:
namespace App7.Clases.BasesDatos 
{     
public interface IFileHelper     
{        
string GetLocalFilePath(string filename);     
} 
}

The code jumps directly to the catch block and does not get the file path
ResultadosBD.cs:
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

namespace App7.Clases.BasesDatos
{
    public partial class ResultadosBD : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly DatosRepository? _datosRepository;

        public ResultadosBD()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
            try
            {
                var fileHelper = DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>();
                if (fileHelper == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("No se pudo obtener una instancia de IFileHelper.");
                }

                string databasePath = fileHelper.GetLocalFilePath("OMSAnthroP.db3");

                 if (File.Exists(databasePath))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"El archivo de base de datos existe en la ruta: {databasePath}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"El archivo de base de datos no existe en la ruta: {databasePath}");
                     CreateDatabaseFile(databasePath);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Archivo de base de datos creado en la ruta: {databasePath}");
                }

                try
                {
                    // Inicializar el repositorio de datos
                    _datosRepository = new DatosRepository(databasePath);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error al inicializar el repositorio de datos: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error al obtener la ruta del archivo: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        private void CreateDatabaseFile(string path)
        {
            // Implementa la lógica para crear el archivo de base de datos aquí
        }
    }
}

FileHelper.cs:
using System;
using System.IO;
using Foundation;
using App7.Clases.BasesDatos;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(App7.iOS.FileHelper))]
namespace App7.iOS
{
    public class FileHelper : IFileHelper
    {
        public string GetLocalFilePath(string filename)
        {
            string downloadPath;

            NSFileManager fileManager = NSFileManager.DefaultManager;
            NSUrl[] urls = fileManager.GetUrls(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User);
            if (urls != null && urls.Length > 0 && urls[0] != null)
            {
                downloadPath = urls[0].Path ?? throw new Exception("El Path de la URL es nulo.");
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("No se pudo obtener el directorio de documentos de la aplicación.");
            }

            return Path.Combine(downloadPath, filename);
        }
    }
}

What could be causing DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>() to always return null in my .NET MAUI for iOS application?
Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

For the maui, you don't have to use the DependencyService to call the platform native code. You can just use Conditional compilation.

thank you very much for the answer, could you give me a little more guidance based on what I require?

In MAUI, if you want to invoke platform code, you may either use Conditional compilation or Partial classes and methods.
Here is a demo using Partial classes and methods.
1.Create a Partial cross-platform class named FileHelperService,
public partial class FileHelperService
{
    public partial string GetLocalFilePath(string filename);
}

2.In Platform/iOS folder,  also create a partial class named FileHelperService to implement the API on iOS platform.
public partial class FileHelperService
{
    public string GetLocalFilePath(string filename)
    {
        string downloadPath;

        NSFileManager fileManager = NSFileManager.DefaultManager;
        NSUrl[] urls = fileManager.GetUrls(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User);
        if (urls != null && urls.Length > 0 && urls[0] != null)
        {
            downloadPath = urls[0].Path ?? throw new Exception("El Path de la URL es nulo.");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("No se pudo obtener el directorio de documentos de la aplicación.");
        }

        return Path.Combine(downloadPath, filename);
    }
}

3.If you want to invoke FileHelperService, do it this way,
    try
    {
        var fileHelper = new FileHelperService();
        string filePath = fileHelper.GetLocalFilePath(filename);
        ...        

    }

